# how to fetch records from other table using inner join

Tags: php, mysql

I have a scenerio that one table returns me multiple ids. Now I want to fetch the records of these ids from other table using same query.
my query is:

```
SELECT `uID` AS `userID`, 
       count(uID) AS `artistTotalViews` 
  FROM `artist_view` 
GROUP BY 
       `uID` 
ORDER BY 
       `artistTotalViews` DESC
```

my result is:

```
userID  ArtistTotalViews
    0   2
    1   2
    5   1
    4   1
    2   1
```

Now I want that on using these userID I can fetch data from other table. Whole row from the other table using same this query but against the userID present in other table.

my table structures are:

the one from which i want to fetch the records:

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for web_user
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `web_user`;
CREATE TABLE `web_user` (
  `uID` int(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `uFname` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `uLname` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `uEmail` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `userName` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `uPassword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `uAddress` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `uCity` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `uState` varchar(5) default NULL,
  `uZipcode` int(8) default NULL,
  `uPhone` varchar(15) default NULL,
  `uImage` varchar(150) default NULL,
  `userType` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `uGenre` int(8) default NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `biography` text,
  `uVerifyCode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `featured` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `activate` tinyint(1) default '0',
  `uStatus` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `uPaid` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`uID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

the one that is working perfect with current query:

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for artist_view
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `artist_view`;
CREATE TABLE `artist_view` (
  `viewID` int(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `uID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `userIP` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`viewID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of artist_view
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `artist_view` VALUES ('1', '5', '203.170.68.22');
INSERT INTO `artist_view` VALUES ('2', '4', '203.170.68.22');
INSERT INTO `artist_view` VALUES ('3', '2', '203.170.68.22');
INSERT INTO `artist_view` VALUES ('4', '1', '203.170.68.22');
INSERT INTO `artist_view` VALUES ('5', '0', '203.170.68.22');
INSERT INTO `artist_view` VALUES ('6', '1', '103.224.14.2');
INSERT INTO `artist_view` VALUES ('7', '0', '103.224.14.2');
```

thank you please.

Comment: you have to use  join based on UserID

Comment: can you please help me implementing? i dont know how to use join. i do know join can help.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did n't get your question, just i guess this can help you my friend:

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM
(SELECT uID AS userID, count(uID) AS artistTotalViews 
FROM artist_view GROUP BY uID ORDER BY artistTotalViews DESC)t1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2 on t1.userID = t2.id;
```

Comment: You answer is perfect buddy. great :)

Comment: your answer helps me figuring this out. thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select web_user.uID,web_user.uFname,web_user.uLname, artist_view.uID
From web_user inner join artist_view
ON web_user.uID = artist_view.uID.



SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;    //tabel1.userID = table2.userID
```

Comment: i want to implement this in my existing query. can you do that?

Comment: means i want to extend my existing query that is already working perfect.

Comment: Yes What is the structure of two-tables

Comment: let me post in my question dear.

Comment: i have posted my table structure

Comment: @Dot_NETJunior : **general tip :** if u want people to have injection prone `sql`, only then quote `w3schools` in your answers!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.*,wu.*
FROM 
(SELECT `uID` AS `userID`,count(uID) AS `artistTotalViews` FROM `artist_view` GROUP BY `uID`) T1
 LEFT JOIN web_user wu  on T1.userID=wu.uID
```